# Problem to return high valor of the function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that returns the highest value of the attribute of an object within an array, always return the initial value of the variable that I output in my function, please any suggestions. Thank you

```js
var lunes = new Weekday("lunes", 5);
var martes = new Weekday("martes", 5);
var miercoles = new Weekday("miercoles", 15);
var jueves = new Weekday("jueves", 30);
var viernes = new Weekday("viernes", 50);

var week = [lunes,martes,miercoles,jueves,viernes] ;

var result = mostPopularDays(week);
console.log(result);

function Weekday (name, traffic) {
    this.name = name;
    this.traffic = traffic;
}

 function mostPopularDays(week) {
  var masPublico = 0;
  
  for(var i=0; i <= week[i] ; i++){
   if(week[i].traffic < masPublico ){
    masPublico = week[i].traffic;
   }
  }
  return masPublico;  
}
```

Comment: Este foro es enspañol, edita la pregunta y cambia el idioma

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Listo amigo ya solucione con tu ejemplo lo único es cambiar la comparación de lugar de esto

```
 if(week[i].traffic <  masPublico){
        masPublico = week[i].traffic;
    }
```

a esto

```
if(masPublico <  week[i].traffic){
        masPublico = week[i].traffic;
    }
```

También tienes que cambiar el `for` que para iterar un objeto tienes que pasarle el total osea `objeto.length` por eso el `for` no funciona espero te funcione

Para obtener el día hacemos un `filter()` de el array y retornamos nada mas el objeto que su `traffic` sea igual al mayor.

```js
var lunes = new Weekday("lunes", 5);

 var martes = new Weekday("martes", 5);

 var miercoles = new Weekday("miercoles", 15);

 var jueves = new Weekday("jueves", 30);

 var viernes = new Weekday("viernes", 50);

 var week = [lunes,martes,miercoles,jueves,viernes] ;

 mostPopularDays(week);

  function Weekday (name, traffic) {

this.name = name;

this.traffic = traffic;

}
   function mostPopularDays(week) {
   
    var masPublico = 0;

    for(var i=0; i < week.length ; i++){
    
        if(masPublico <  week[i].traffic){
            masPublico = week[i].traffic;
        }
    }
    var dia = week.filter((item)=>{
      return item.traffic == masPublico
    })

    console.log(dia[0].name,masPublico)
    return masPublico;  
}
```

Te dejo un ejemplo de como obtener el valor mas alto de un `array` espero te ayude

la idea es iterar el arreglo y comparar el valor con el máximo que se va agregando al encontrar uno mayor al anterior.

```js
var values = [5,10,25,8,12],
    max = 0;

for(var i=0,len=values.length;i<len;i++){
    if(max < values[i]){
        max = values[i];
    }
}
console.log(max)
```

Comment: Perfecto amigo muchas gracias algo tan sencillo pero de verdad que me llevo un rato y me venci jeje. Un abrazo

Comment: que bueno si te funciono dale como respuesta correcta para que los demás programadores encuentren la solución saludos y que bueno ayudarte

Comment: Perdón amigo soy nuevo aquí no veo la opción para darle respuesta correcta me pudiera indicar?

Comment: es arriba en la respuesta en la esquina donde estan las flechas dale hacia arriba si es una respuesta que aporta y al check si es la correcta

Comment: Creo que ya esta ?

Comment: si amigo muchas gracias espero que la solución te funcione cualquier cosa estamos a la orden.

Comment: Las preguntas escritas en inglés no se deben de responder hasta que OP la traduzca a español, es importante usar el sitio como se debe y no apoyar estas malas practicas...

Comment: Esta bien amigo, lo tomaré en cuenta para la próxima, gracias por el dato.

Comment: @user3821102 has de traducir la pregunta para que sea valida en el sitio